# Was it a mucus or a spider's web? How can a mucus look like a spider's web?

Tags: gastropod

Today I found a small slug, 35-40 mm dangling on a shiny thread from a branch 175 cm above me. I thought that the slug had slid on a spider's web, so I touched it and it instantly snapped and the slug fell on the floor. I think it was wet and was mucus. How can a slug mucus, in 5-12'C, become 2 meters long, 50 microns wide and hold a slug from a branch?

Comment: Fascinating, I do not understand why down voting has become more prevalent in this community. Nonetheless, this question pertains to biophysics, materials science and biochemistry. I am by no means an expert in any of these fields. I assume the phenomenon you observed was due to the unique physical and chemical properties of the mucus, as well as the temperature experienced (5-12°C is quite cool) which would have altered the properties of the mucus.

Comment: Using Google Scholar, I was able to yield these results: '*The Physical Properties of the Pedal Mucus of the Terrestrial Slug, Ariolimax Columbianus*', '*The role of mucus in the locomotion and adhesion of the pulmonate slug, Ariolimax Columbianus*', '*Mechanical Properties of Pedal Mucus and Their Consequences for Gastropod Structure and Performance*' and '*The role of gastropod pedal mucus in locomotion*', which may provide interesting information to your question, but not answer it, such is the nature of science, we can not 'know' something.

Comment: Lastly, if you do not have a background in these fields, it can be extremely frustrating trying to read and comprehend scientific articles. This is by convention and in my opinion by mistake, since articles narrow their audience significantly, by lacking explanations of prerequisite concepts and critical background information, and context.  For example, in science often people will tell you that something is, not *how* we figured out or have reason to believe that it is. Meaning readers can not formulate an idea on the level of human understanding of a specific subject.

Comment: This is a separate matter, hopefully someone answer your question by using logic and outlining the limitations of our knowledge on the subject.

Comment: Hey thanks a lot for the comments, I will look into it. I just had an idea that the slug gelatin became some kind of organized cylinder of organized organic chemistry called mucins and when I touched it with my hand the dryness and oil of my hand instantly disrupted the organic chemistry and it just exploded like when glass that is under pressure erupts. I was stupid not to examine if the mucus was had conpletely sprung up or if was a web cos I was just confused.